# redirect from one domain to another using Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, amazon-route53

I have two domains `doma.example` and `domb.example`, both of them are using Route53 as their DNS.
I need to redirect `suba.doma.example` to `new.domb.example`.
I am not clear what DNS entries I need to create for each of those domains.

Comment: Your question is off topic here as not related to programming, look at [su] probably instead or [sf] depending on the context. Did you look at Route53 documentation or do a search on StackExchange as there are tons of questions and answers for such topics?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes- I did search, plenty of questions, but no answer to the specific one I asked. I should have specified I know how to do it using S3 or a header: location. I am trying to achive this between two different hosted zones (both I control) and just Route53

Answer (score -1):

You could create a CNAME record in the public hosted zone for `suba.doma.example` which points to `new.domb.example`. [1][2]

#### References

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html - see table column "CNAME Records"

Comment: The document you specified seems to state you create an alias to another record in the **same** hosted zone, not a different one. Am I missinterpreting it?

Comment: Yes, the alias works for the same hosted zone only. CNAME should work across zones as long as it is not the zone apex you are redirecting.

Comment: it seems I have to do something in both hosted zones to make this happens or the CNAME syntax as I see in the documents does not provide the behavior I am looking for.

Comment: Let me put the question another way: Is suba.doma.example the zone apex of your public hosted zone in AWS?
Knowing this is important to configure it correctly, since a workaround is needed for that case.

Comment: @MarinLoper the apex domains are doma.example and domb.example

Comment: Ok, so it should be no problem to create a CNAME entry "new.domb.example" for the hosted zone "doma.example". Click on "Hosted Zones" and select the name of your hosted zone "doma.example". Then click on "Create Record Set". Choose Name "suba" and type "CNAME", Alias "No" and Value "new.domb.example". Next, check that a record for "new.domb.example" exists. Where is "new.domb.example" pointing at in your case? At an A-Record?

Comment: OK, thats good. Did you try to create the CNAME record and look at the output of the nslookup command by querying suba.doma.example?